# ckeditor or drupal keeps adding closing source tag /> at the end of <source> tag. Using Video Plugin for ckeditor

Tags: 7, wysiwyg, files, nodes

I am using the ckeditor for drupal and the video plugin for it to embed video's to site. I have tried to edit the Video plugin javascript file like below so it will spit out something like this `<source scr="" type="">` but have had no luck.

`innerHtml = '<cke:source src="'+video.src+'" type="'+video.type+'">';`

However once I go to click okay ckeditor or drupal adds a closing slash at the end of the source tag to make it look like this:

```
<source scr="" type="" />
```

I have turned off "Correct faulty and chopped off HTML" and it still adds it at the end.

Even when viewing source view of the content editor there is /> present.

Is it ckeditor or drupal adding this at the end of source tags and how can I remove it?

Using CKEditor 7.x-1.16
Video Plugin for ckeditor